# leitura de arquivo .XLSX no R

Tags: r

Qual o problema e/ou diferença entre eu ler um arquivo em `.txt` e `.xlsx` no `R`?

Lendo em `.xlsx` posso ter mais problemas que em `.txt` durante uma análise ?

Um amigo me pediu para fazer tudo em `.txt` porque é melhor mas não entendi o porque.

Outro detalhe é que tenho um arquivo em `.xlsx` com 4 abas (sheets) e quando troco o nome da aba no script ele continua lendo o anterior. 
Isso é devido ser Excel ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual o problema e/ou diferença entre eu ler um arquivo em `.txt` e `.xlsx` no R?

A rigor, nenhuma. Ambas são maneiras válidas de se armazenar dados para análise, assim como `.csv`, `.sav` e `.dat` também são. O único senão em utilizar `.xlsx` é necessitar, quase que obrigatoriamente, de um editor de planilhas para visualizar os arquivos, enquanto o formato `.txt` pode ser lido pro praticamente qualquer programa instalado no computador.

> Lendo em `.xlsx` posso ter mais problemas que em `.txt` durante uma análise?

Se a leitura de ambos os arquivos foi feita corretamente, não devem ocorrer problemas durante a análise dos dados.

> Um amigo me pediu para fazer tudo em `.txt` porque é melhor mas não entendi o porquê.

Veja a primeira resposta que dei. Além disso, pode ser apenas preferência pessoal dele. Particularmente, prefiro arquivos `.txt` e `.csv` porque consigo lê-los diretamente no terminal, sem precisar de programas adicionais. Além de, claro, o espaço ocupado em disco por arquivos `.txt` é menor do que o espaço ocupado por arquivos `.xlsx` (embora nos dias atuais isso não seja tão relevante assim).

> Outro detalhe é que tenho um arquivo em .xlsx com 4 abas (sheets) e quando troco o nome da aba no script ele continua lendo o anterior. Isso é devido ser Excel?

Eu não tenho como te responder esta pergunta porque não tenho o teu código disponível. Assim, não consigo avaliar o que poderia estar errado nele ou até mesmo no arquivo `.xlsx` a ser lido. O que posso afirmar é que utilizo algo similar ao código abaixo quando trabalho com pessoas que utilizam o Excel e este código, quando adaptado às necessidades de cada análise, funciona muito bem, mesmo em arquivos `.xlsx` com mais de uma sheet. Eu apenas altero o parâmetro `sheet=1` para `sheet=2` a fim de ler uma sheet diferente. Eu não as chamo pelo nome, mas sim pela posição dentro do arquivo `.xlsx`.

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("arquivo.xlsx", sheet=1, col_names=TRUE)
read_excel("arquivo.xlsx", sheet=2, col_names=TRUE)
```

Note que é necessário instalar o pacote `readxl` antes de rodar os comandos acima.

Comment: Prezado Marcos Nunes e Marcelo de Andrade.
Muito obrigado pela sua resposta e esclarecedora, realmente me ajudou muito. Quanto ao erro que reportei, já foi corrigido. Havia um espaço a mais, que não tinha observado. Já tenho mais de um pacote para excel, o xlsx e esse que vc me falou. Como sou iniciante no R provavelmente iremos conversar outras vezes e claro vc sempre ajudando com respostas diretas. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Que bom saber disso, Herlon. Já que a resposta foi útil, considere votar nela [como explicado neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), pois assim os usuários do site são recompensados e se sentem compelidos a continuar ajudando os demais usuários.

Answer (score 5):

Bom ainda existem algumas diferenças que são importantes em relação aos dois formatos e em geral eu diria que seu amigo está certo.

*1) a leitura do txt é mais rápida e você não depende muito de pacotes externos ou outras linguagens.*

Até pouco tempo atrás nós não tínhamos o pacote `readxl`, que é uma mão não roda para leitura do excel. Você tinha que optar por pacotes como `xlsx` ou `XLconnect` ou `openxlsx` ou (vários outros pacotes)... e cada um deles tem uma dependência externa diferente (Java, C++, etc.). Dessa forma, era muito comum ter problemas de compatibilidade para ler arquivos excel.

Além disso, ainda é muito mais rápido ler arquivos txt.

*2) para salvar arquivos excel você provavelmente pode enfrentar problemas de compatibilidade*

Ainda não temos um pacote bom e confiável como o `readxl` para salvar arquivos excel. Então você vai ter que usar um desses que mencionei e mesmo que tudo funcione corretamente no seu computador, no computador de seu amigo ou outras pessoas pode dar problema.

*3) excel tem limitação de linhas*

No excel você tem uma limitação no número de linhas. Além disso os arquivos ficam desnecessariamente pesados. Se você for trabalhar com bases de dados grandes, esqueça.

Dessa forma, você tem que pensar para quê você quer salvar em excel, caso contrário trabalhe com o txt.

Existem situações em que salvar em excel é útil, em geral quando você quer apresentar o resultado final em uma planilha de excel. Mas veja que isso ocorre geralmente na etapa final da análise. Enquanto você estiver manipulando e trocando base de dados, é interessante evitar esse formato.

Comment: Prezado Carlos, muito obrigado por agregar informações. É exatamente isso que estou passando minha base é muito grande e no pc do meu amigo em questão o R não lê. Preciso exercitar a transformação em .txt. Obrigado